# SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 installation issue

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Hi i installed SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 in visual studio 2013. I selected tools after Extensions and updates option after that i installed SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 . The installation was successful i restarted the system.

But after when i click on add reference it is not showing sqlite for windows phone 8.1 .Please see below image for further information. I am unable to see this option.

Could any one advise me.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to directly use the extension, but most online guides ask you to install the 'sqlite.net' package from NuGet as well. You then add a reference to this and it allow you to use the sqlite extension through easy to use wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

I did not seen SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 option but i able to do Sqlite operations.